# xslt to add existing node in xml to another node based on a particular value using for each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which has a set of order numbers and one or more lineitems under each of the order number. I need to have the value of the order numbers in one more place as given below.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <orders>
    <orderHeader>
      <requestDttm>1900-01-01T01:01:01-06:00</requestDttm>
      <orderCount>1</orderCount>
    </orderHeader>
    <orderPayload>
      <order>
        <createTimestamp>2015-06-11</createTimestamp>
        <orderID>ES123456</orderID>
        <customer>
          <dayPhone>dayPhone1</dayPhone>
          <email>email1</email>
          <firstName>Test</firstName>
          <lastName>Customer1</lastName>
        </customer>
        <fullfillment>
          <taxAmount>3</taxAmount>
          <totalPrice>25</totalPrice>
        </fullfillment> 
        <lineItem>
          <sku>sku1</sku>
          <price>10</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </lineItem>
        <lineItem>
          <sku>sku2</sku>
          <price>10</price>
          <quantity>2</quantity>
        </lineItem>
        <lineItem>
          <sku>sku3</sku>
          <price>5</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </lineItem>
        <pickupLocation>
          <outletID>4804</outletID>
          <outletAddress1>outletAddress1</outletAddress1>
          <outletAddress2>outletAddress2</outletAddress2>
          <city>Texas</city>
          <stateCode>TX</stateCode>
          <country>US</country>
          <postalCode>602</postalCode>
        </pickupLocation>
      </order>
      <order>
        <createTimestamp>2015-06-12</createTimestamp>
        <orderID>orderID2</orderID>
        <customer>
          <dayPhone>dayPhone2</dayPhone>
          <email>email2</email>
          <firstName>Test</firstName>
          <lastName>Customer2</lastName>
        </customer>
        <fullfillment>
          <taxAmount>10</taxAmount>
          <totalPrice>40</totalPrice>
        </fullfillment>
        <lineItem>
          <sku>sku4</sku>
          <price>20</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </lineItem>
        <lineItem>
          <sku>sku5</sku>
          <price>10</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </lineItem>
        <lineItem>
          <sku>sku6</sku>
          <price>5</price>
          <quantity>2</quantity>
        </lineItem>
        <pickupLocation>
          <outletID>outletID2</outletID>
          <outletAddress1>outletAddress12</outletAddress1>
          <outletAddress2>outletAddress22</outletAddress2>
          <city>Topeka</city>
          <stateCode>KS</stateCode>
          <country>US</country>
          <postalCode>601</postalCode>
        </pickupLocation>
      </order>
      <order>
        <createTimestamp>2015-06-12</createTimestamp>
        <orderID>orderID3</orderID>
        <customer>
          <dayPhone>dayPhone3</dayPhone>
          <email>email3</email>
          <firstName>firstName3</firstName>
          <lastName>lastName3</lastName>
        </customer>
        <fullfillment>
          <taxAmount>2</taxAmount>
          <totalPrice>5</totalPrice>
        </fullfillment>
        <lineItem>
          <sku>sku7</sku>
          <price>5</price>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </lineItem>
        <pickupLocation>
          <outletID>7304</outletID>
          <outletAddress1>outletAddress13</outletAddress1>
          <outletAddress2>outletAddress23</outletAddress2>
          <city>cucta</city>
          <stateCode>CU</stateCode>
          <country>CO</country>
          <postalCode>214</postalCode>
        </pickupLocation>
      </order>
    </orderPayload>
  </orders>
```

**OUTPUT XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <orderHeader>
        <requestDttm>1900-01-01T01:01:01-06:00</requestDttm>
        <orderCount>1</orderCount>
    </orderHeader>
    <orderPayload>
        <order>
            <createTimestamp>2015-06-11</createTimestamp>
            <orderID>ES123456</orderID>
            <customer>
                <dayPhone>dayPhone1</dayPhone>
                <email>email1</email>
                <firstName>Test</firstName>
                <lastName>Customer1</lastName>
            </customer>
            <fullfillment>
                <taxAmount>3</taxAmount>
                <totalPrice>25</totalPrice>
            </fullfillment>
            <lineItem>
                <orderNumber>ES123456</orderNumber>
                <sku>sku1</sku>
                <price>10</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <orderNumber>ES123456</orderNumber>
                <sku>sku2</sku>
                <price>10</price>
                <quantity>2</quantity>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <orderNumber>ES123456</orderNumber>
                <sku>sku3</sku>
                <price>5</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </lineItem>
            <pickupLocation>
                <outletID>4804</outletID>
                <outletAddress1>outletAddress1</outletAddress1>
                <outletAddress2>outletAddress2</outletAddress2>
                <city>Texas</city>
                <stateCode>TX</stateCode>
                <country>US</country>
                <postalCode>602</postalCode>
            </pickupLocation>
        </order>
        <order>
            <createTimestamp>2015-06-12</createTimestamp>
            <orderID>orderID2</orderID>
            <customer>
                <dayPhone>dayPhone2</dayPhone>
                <email>email2</email>
                <firstName>Test</firstName>
                <lastName>Customer2</lastName>
            </customer>
            <fullfillment>
                <taxAmount>10</taxAmount>
                <totalPrice>40</totalPrice>
            </fullfillment>
            <lineItem>
                <orderNumber>orderID2</orderNumber>
                <sku>sku4</sku>
                <price>20</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <orderNumber>orderID2</orderNumber>
                <sku>sku5</sku>
                <price>10</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <orderNumber>orderID2</orderNumber>
                <sku>sku6</sku>
                <price>5</price>
                <quantity>2</quantity>
            </lineItem>
            <pickupLocation>
                <outletID>outletID2</outletID>
                <outletAddress1>outletAddress12</outletAddress1>
                <outletAddress2>outletAddress22</outletAddress2>
                <city>Topeka</city>
                <stateCode>KS</stateCode>
                <country>US</country>
                <postalCode>601</postalCode>
            </pickupLocation>
        </order>
        <order>
            <createTimestamp>2015-06-12</createTimestamp>
            <orderID>orderID3</orderID>
            <customer>
                <dayPhone>dayPhone3</dayPhone>
                <email>email3</email>
                <firstName>firstName3</firstName>
                <lastName>lastName3</lastName>
            </customer>
            <fullfillment>
                <taxAmount>2</taxAmount>
                <totalPrice>5</totalPrice>
            </fullfillment>
            <lineItem>
                <orderNumber>orderID3</orderNumber>
                <sku>sku7</sku>
                <price>5</price>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </lineItem>
            <pickupLocation>
                <outletID>7304</outletID>
                <outletAddress1>outletAddress13</outletAddress1>
                <outletAddress2>outletAddress23</outletAddress2>
                <city>cucta</city>
                <stateCode>CU</stateCode>
                <country>CO</country>
                <postalCode>214</postalCode>
            </pickupLocation>
        </order>
    </orderPayload>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have a for-each loop in this. First, you need to have an identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, target the node that you want to override. In this case, then node `lineItem`

```
<xsl:template match="lineItem">
    <xsl:copy>
        <orderNumber><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::order/orderID"/></orderNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

thus the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="lineItem">
        <xsl:copy>
            <orderNumber><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::order/orderID"/></orderNumber>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you...!! it works fine...being new to xslt is difficult indeed.